# How to update the pointer in the calling function?

Tags: c++

I have a linked list. In the calling function, I created the first node and I passed the pointer of that first node to a function for further processing. The additional nodes are created in that function. But for some reason, during the processing in the function that first node has to be deleted. So in the processing function, the linked list's first node address is changed to the next node. But when return to the calling function, that change is not reflected in the calling function. In the calling function, the linked list's first node is still the deleted first node, how can I update?

Inside calling function:

```
model_list *allmodelroot;

allmodelroot =  new model_list;
allmodelroot->next = NULL;
allmodelroot->modelIndex = -1;  
processfunction(bmodelroot, wmodelroot, settings, featurePts, allmodelroot);
```

Inside process function;

```
int processfunction(model_list *bmodelroot, model_list *wmodelroot, set_setting &settings, calib_features &featurePts, model_list *allmodelroot)
{
    model_list *first_allmodelroot = allmodelroot;  


    model_list *previous = allmodelroot;
   for(i = 0; i < allmodelrootSize; i++)
   {

       if(usemodel[i] == false)
       {
               //delete the first node
               first_allmodelroot = allmodelroot->next;
               previous = allmodelroot->next;
               delete allmodelroot;
               allmodelroot = previous;



       }else{
          previous = allmodelroot;
          allmodelroot = allmodelroot->next;
       }

   }

   allmodelroot = first_allmodelroot;   

}
```

Comment: Some code would help...

Comment: This is like trying to debug a programming problem over the phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a full understand about the pointer.
In short words: The pointer itself has an address in memory, but its value is the address of other variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pointer_test(char *p) {
    printf("p addr \t:%d\n", (int)p);
    p = p + 1;
    printf("p addr \t:%d\n", (int)p);
}
int main() {
    char buf[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    printf("buf addr\t:%d\n", (int) buf);
    printf("buf[0] addr\t:%d\n", (int) &buf[0]);
    printf("buf[1] addr\t:%d\n", (int) &buf[1]);
    printf("buf[2] addr\t:%d\n", (int) &buf[2]);
    pointer_test(buf);
    printf("buf addr\t:%d\n", (int) buf);
    printf("buf[0] addr\t:%d\n", (int) &buf[0]);
    printf("buf[1] addr\t:%d\n", (int) &buf[1]);
    printf("buf[2] addr\t:%d\n", (int) &buf[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, value of p is the address of buf, address of p is in the stack or just a register.
The address of buf is copped to function pointer_test as the value of p.
Changing the value of p, cannot affect buf for this case.
Output of the above code may be like below:

```
buf addr        :2686736
buf[0] addr     :2686736
buf[1] addr     :2686737
buf[2] addr     :2686738
p addr  :2686736
p addr  :2686737
buf addr        :2686736
buf[0] addr     :2686736
buf[1] addr     :2686737
buf[2] addr     :2686738
```

For your case, if you want to modify the value of allmodelroot, `model_list **allmodelroot` should be used, which means passing the address of pointer allmodelroot. Once you get the original address of pointer allmodelroot, then it's possible to change the value of pointer allmdelroot inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the code a structure representing the linked list *itself*, not a pointer to the first node in the list. If you have no such structure, I'd say that's a pretty big defect in your code.

Comment: Or he's passing pointers by value, changing them, and wondering why the caller scope's version isn't updated...

Comment: @ausairman That's another way of saying precisely the same thing. A pointer to where the pointer to the first element is stored is a structure representing the linked list itself. A pointer to the first element, however, cannot represent the linked list *itself* because the linked list can have different first elements and still be the same list.

Comment: suggest me, what is the way should be?

Comment: @batuman Create some structure that represents the linked list *itself*.

Comment: @David Schwartz; Can show me how to be? Could you answer my question?

Comment: Thanks now understand. I passed the reference of that pointer. Now it works